# My new blog header image is not displaying... How to I correctly write the code?

Tags: php, css

From what I can understand I may need to modify both the header.php file as well as the style.css file. I've uploaded the image to the hosting website and I believe it is a relative link: (/public_html/wp-content/themes/sandbox/Header-1.jpg)

So. This is the style.css code I have:

```
#header { border-bottom:none;
    height:200px;
    padding-top:0;
    padding-bottom:0;
    background:url("/public_html/wp-content/themes/kid/Header-1.jpg")
    no-repeat bottom center; }


#headerimg  {
      height: 200px; 
      width: 800px; }
```

This is the original php in header.php

```
<div id="header">
        <h1 id="blog-title"><span><a href="<?php bloginfo('home') ?>/" title="<?php echo wp_specialchars( get_bloginfo('name'), 1 ) ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo('name') ?></a></span></h1>
        <div id="blog-description"><?php bloginfo('description') ?></div>
    </div><!--  #header -->
```

I've tried replacing the h1 id and the div id lines with

```
<img src= "/public_html/wp-content/themes/sandbox/Header-1.jpg"/>
```

but that wasn't effective.

Right now the website has no header and can be seen here: [www.dearjasmina.com](http://www.dearjasmina.com)

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

The path you're using is incorrect. It should be `/wp-content/themes/sandbox/Header-1.jpg`.

So you're css should read

```
#header {
    height:200px;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    background:url('/wp-content/themes/kid/Header-1.jpg') no-repeat bottom center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#header { border-bottom:none;
    height:200px;
    padding-top:0;
    padding-bottom:0;
    background:url("/wp-content/themes/kid/Header-1.jpg")
    no-repeat bottom center; }


#headerimg  {
      height: 200px; 
      width: 800px; }
```

Your background is actually at
http://www.dearjasmina.com/wp-content/themes/sandbox/Header-1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though the relative-URL is incorrect. Try removing the `/public-html`.

Answer (score 0):

remove public_html folder in your image path, use like below
`<img src="/wp-content/themes/sandbox/Header-1.jpg">`

Answer (score 0):

There's a 404 Not Found on your image, according to IE Network Sniffing. Double check your url.